# Memory Caching in WCF Rest Services

Tags: wcf, rest, caching, memorycache

I am using MemoryCache in my WCF Rest Service. First time I hit the Database and cache the data in the Memory cache.

I have implemented it successfully. In my project, I have a requirement. I need to check cache key insertion time.

I want to add a condition if cache key is more then 15 minutes, I will again update the cache key.

I know that I can use

```
policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(15);
```

If I use this code, it will expire after 15 minutes.

Is there any way to know that when a cachekey insert into cache?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228244(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: HI Amit. Please send me correct link. Your link is regarding outputcache.

Comment: Are you looking for a [SlidingExpiration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy.slidingexpiration.aspx)?  (Where the cache items will expire after a time period after the last time it was accessed)

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate your data in an object which contains ModificationTime property and cache this object.

```
class CacheData<T>
{
    public DateTime ModificationTime { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

You can create an instance of this object, set the time and data properties and cache with a cache key.